# How do I set my RadioButtons to increase the score only once even after being clicked multiple times?

Tags: android, radio-button

My issue currently is that I have set a scoring system to each of my radio buttons in my radio group however when I click the radio button multiple times or change my answer the score keeps on increasing. How do I set it so that the score only increases once when the radio button is clicked and when the answer is changed it will show the score of only the new option selected?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int score = 0;
public TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    //is the current radio button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    //now check which radio button is selected
    //android switch statement
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton:
            if (checked)
                score += 1;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if (checked)
                score += 1;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if (checked)
                score += 3;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton4:
            if (checked)
                score += 5;
            break;
    }
    updateScore(score);
}


public void updateScore(int score) {
    tv.setText(" " + score);
}
}
```

Comment: Disable the RadioGroup once one of its RadioButtons has been clicked.

Comment: and how do I do that @ModularSynth? I'm kinda new to coding so any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: set its enabled state to false

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem completely. If you want the score to change according to options, you can do either of following -

1. Make `score` variable as a local variable.
   OR
2. Don't add the `score` of this option to previous `score` i.e. Replace `+=` by `=` everywhere i.e.

   ```
   score = 1;
   ```

Comment: the 2nd option works however when I answer the next question the score does not update to the new score. it is stuck on the previous answer's score

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal, you will be needing to store every radio button entry. Before adding score first you need to check if the entry already exists if not then add score else ignore. You may use HashMap class to save entry of radio button. Save radio button id as a key of hash map before adding entry to hash map check if this key already exists. This would help you. Adding code to help you.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    //is the current radio button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    //now check which radio button is selected
    //android switch statement
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton:
            if (!radioButtonRecord.containsKey(view.getId())) {
                score += 1;
                radioButtonRecord.put(view.getId(), true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if (!radioButtonRecord.containsKey(view.getId())) {
                score += 1;
                radioButtonRecord.put(view.getId(), true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if (!radioButtonRecord.containsKey(view.getId())) {
                score += 1;
                radioButtonRecord.put(view.getId(), true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton4:
            if (!radioButtonRecord.containsKey(view.getId())) {
                score += 1;
                radioButtonRecord.put(view.getId(), true);
            }
            break;
    }
    updateScore(score);
}
```

Use below code outside the onnCreate method

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> radioButtonRecord;
```

And inside oncreate method use below code

```
radioButtonRecord = new HashMap<>();
```

For further help how hashmap works, refer below links

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/
```

Comment: I should try this and see. Do you know any good links that can help me get this done? I'm pretty new to coding and so any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I truly appreciate it! @Mr Mystery